# Swift: Execute defer statement on exit of parent/caller's scope instead of scope of current functions

Tags: swift

I understand that in Swift, code in the `defer` block would execute immediately after the current scope has exited, regardless of the control flow in the function below, for example:

```
func someFunc() {
    defer {
        print("Prints when someFunc() exits, no matter the control flow below")
    }
    // Arbitrary control flow (if, else with returns. Completion calls, etc.)
}
```

However, is it possible for the `defer` block in a callee to execute after the scope of its caller has exited? For example:

```
func calleeFunc() {
    defer {
        print("Called when callerFunc() is exited!")
    }
}

func callerFunc() {
    calleeFunc()
    print("This will print BEFORE \"Called when callerFunc() is exited!\")
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: no. you would need; defer { calleFunc())

Comment: Got it, so it seems that a defer {} block would always be needed if we want to execute any arbitrary code immediately after the current scope exits. There doesn't seem to be any "magical" way to abstract the behavior of a defer{} block inside another function.